# Nothing in a Query

Tags: query

In Mathematica 10, `Nothing` is defined as to automaticaly disappear when used in a list or in an association, and moreover with the property that it returns `Nothing` when called with any number of arguments.

Consider the following Query:

```
(Query[f][{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}]

(* f[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}] *)
```

Hence, when we use `Nothing` instead of `f`, I expected the result to be `Nothing[{1,2,3,4,5}]`, wich evaluates to `Nothing`. However:

```
Query[Nothing][{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}]

(* {1, 2, 3, 4, 5} *)
```

The expression `Nothing` cannot be used as a part specification, but here it behaves like the part specification `All`. So is `Nothing` `All` in Queries?

Comment: With `Trace` you will see that `Nothing` will go though `List` and disappear. I don't know how to judge this behavior though.

Comment: `Query[Nothing] // Normal` returns `Identity`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `Query[Nothing][{1, 2, 3}] // Trace` to catch a problematic moment:

```
Dataset`Query`PackagePrivate`compile0[
   {Nothing}, 
   OptionValue[ Query, {}, {FailureAction, PartBehavior, MissingBehavior}]
]
```

and subsequent evaluation of `{Nothing}` to `{}`, from now on, there will be no trace of `Nothing` and `Identity` is called:

```
 Dataset`Query`PackagePrivate`compile0[{}, {"Abort", Automatic, Automatic}]
```

> ```
> Dataset`OverrideMissing[GeneralUtilities`Checked[Identity, Identity]]
> ```

while `...Checked[Nothing, Identity]` could work.

I don't know if that's expected or not.

p.s. if you want to use it as an operator, use `Query[Nothing &]`

Comment: Yes, this shows where and how Nothing is ignored during the evaluation. Nice to see!

Answer (score 1):

```
 Query[Nothing][{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}]
=
  Query[][{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}]
=
  {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Since `Query[Nothing]` gives `Query[Nothing]` I would argue.

Comment: As @Kuba has shown, Nothing does not disappear in Query. Nevertheless, I think you are close to an explanation. I tested the following three cases: Query[1,All,1][{{1}}], Query[1, Nothing,1][{{1}}], Query[1, 1][{{1}}]. It gives me the impression that Nothing is simply ignored during the evaluation. That also answers my question. Nothing is not All.