# Nothing not behaving as expected?

Tags: evaluation

I was thinking that Nothing was doing the same job as the vanishing sequence ##&[].

Yet this exemple shows it doesn't.

```
Association[If[True,Nothing]] (*returns Association[Nothing]*)
Association[If[True,##&[]]] (*returns Association[]*)
```

Is it normal ?

Comment: Which *Mathematica* version do you use? With version 10.4.1 `Association[If[True, Nothing]]` returns `<||>`.

Comment: ref: "represents an element of a **list** that will automatically be removed. " the  list is a key here.

Comment: So it behaves correctly, but worth to mention that one can't predict what is done internally: [**102555**](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/102555/5478)

Comment: I should have checked first, this also works with version 10.4.0.  So what version is it not working in?

Comment: According to Heidegger: "The Nothing itself nothings", but I'm sure he didn't have MMA in mind when he wrote that.

Answer (score 15):

`Nothing` is like `Sequence[]`: it gets removed during evaluation.  But there is one significant difference: *it only gets removed from lists*.

```
{{Nothing}, {Sequence[]}}
(* {{}, {}} *)

{foo[Nothing], foo[Sequence[]]}
(* {foo[Nothing], foo[]} *)
```

---

**Update from @ilian**

> It only gets removed from lists is correct for Mathematica 10.4.0 and later; Nothing did get removed from associations in 10.2 and 10.3.

---

This makes it easier to work with `Nothing` than `Sequence[]` (or at least it requires a less complete understanding of the evaluation sequence before one can use it productively).

Example:

```
{1, 2, 3, 4} /. x_Integer :> If[OddQ[x], x, Sequence[]]
(* {1, Null, 3, Null} *)
```

Oops!  Why didn't this remove the even numbers?  It just replaced them with `Null`!  This can be confusing for something not experienced with `Sequence[]`.  The explanation is that `Sequence[]` gets removed from `If` before the evaluation of `If` starts, so we effectively end up with `If[OddQ[x], x]`, which evaluates to `Null`.  The traditional solution is `If[OddQ[x], x, Unevaluated@Sequence[]]`

With `Nothing`, we can simply use

```
{1, 2, 3, 4} /. x_Integer :> If[OddQ[x], x, Nothing]
```

This reads in a clear, intuitive way: *"Replace odd numbers with themselves and even numbers with nothing."*  In the most common use case, i.e. list manipulation, it behave according to the most naive expectation.

---

Side note:  `Association[something]` is not correct syntax in the sense that it does not evaluate to a true association data structure.

```
AssociationQ@Association[something]
(* False *)
```

`Association["foo" -> something]` does evaluate to a real association.

---

Since you mention the vanishing function `##&[]`, I want to point out an important difference between it and `Sequence[]`/`Nothing`:

Both `Sequence[]` and `Nothing` are removed at the beginning of the [evaluation sequence](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/Evaluation.html), *before* any transformation rules are tried at all.

`##&[]` simply evaluates to `Sequence[]`, which then is treated as usual.  Thus it behaves the same as `vanisher := Sequence[]` would.

This causes differences like the following:

```
{Hold[Sequence[]], Hold[## &[]]}
(* {Hold[], Hold[(##1 &)[]]} *)

{{If[False, x, Sequence[]]}, {If[False, x, ## &[]]}}
(* {{Null}, {}} *)
```

Comment: @Kuba My *guess* for why it was added is what I just described in the update.

Comment: I think it is a good guess. +1

Comment: *It only gets removed from lists* is correct for Mathematica 10.4.0 and later; `Nothing` did get removed from associations in 10.2 and 10.3. Also `Information[Nothing]` is apparently in need of fixing.

Comment: @ilian - I wouldn't have expected it but recently saw some code with `<|"key"->val,"key2"->val2,Nothing|>` and thought it odd that the `Nothing` disappears.  I guess a list is used as an intermediate